# Filterable Listview in Tabstrip Kendo UI

Tags: jquery, listview, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I have a 3 tabbed tabstrip with Kendo UI, each tab having it's own filterable-listview. How can i populate a listview when its own tab is selected? I have a method called mobilelistviewfiltering which is supposed to populate the first listview, so i want it to execute when the first tab is selected. Any idea how?

I'd be glad.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/application/index">
      <style>html { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />
      <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1411/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="videos" style="height:100%;" data-role="view"  data-show="videoShow">
         <header data-role="header">
            <div data-role="navbar">
               <a data-role="backbutton" data-align="left">Geri</a>
               <span data-role="view-title"></span>
            </div>
         </header>
         <div class="test" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="demo-section k-header">
               <div id="tabstrip" class="whatever">
                  <ul>
                     <li class="k-state-active" style="width:18%;">
                        Hepsi
                     </li>
                     <li style="width:38%;">
                        En Beğenilenler
                     </li>
                     <li style="width:43%;">
                        En Çok İzlenenler
                     </li>
                  </ul>
                  <div class="realContent" data-init="mobileListViewFiltering">
                     <ul id="filterable-listview" data-bind="mobileListViewFiltering" data-role="listview" data-source="foo" data-pull-to-refresh="true" data-append-on-refresh="true" data-template="foo-template">
                     </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="realContent" data-init="mobileListViewFiltering">
                     <ul id="filterable-listview" data-role="listview" data-source="foo" data-pull-to-refresh="true" data-append-on-refresh="true" data-template="foo-template">
                     </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="realContent" data-init="mobileListViewFiltering">
                     <ul id="filterable-listview" data-role="listview" data-source="foo" data-pull-to-refresh="true" data-append-on-refresh="true" data-template="foo-template">
                     </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <style scoped>
               #tabstrip {
               font-weight: lighter;
               font-size: 0.9em;
               line-height: 1;
               padding: 0;
               margin: 0;
               }
            </style>
         </div>
         <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
                    animation:  {
                        open: {
                            effects: "fadeIn"
                        }
                    }
                });
                $(".realContent").height($(document).height());
            });
         </script>                                                                                                 
         <script>
            function videoShow(e) {
                                var dynoTitle = e.view.params.tit;
                                    var navbar = app.view()
                                    .header
                                        .find(".km-navbar")
                                            .data("kendoMobileNavBar");
            
                                                  navbar.title(dynoTitle);
            }
                
                
                
            
            
         </script>  
         <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="foo-template">
            <img src="content/#=ProductID#.jpg" alt="#=ProductName# image" class="pullImage"/>
              
            <h3>  #:ProductName# </h3>
            #:UnitsInStock# adet mevcut
         </script>   
         <script>
            var i = 0;
            
            // datasource below is customized for demo purposes.
                        function mobileListViewFiltering() {
            var foo = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            
                        transport: {
            
                            read: {
            
                                url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
            
                            }
            
                        },
                        requestStart: function() {
                                kendo.ui.progress($("#products"), true);
                            },
                            requestEnd: function() {
                                kendo.ui.progress($("#products"), false);
                            },
            
                            
            
                        sort: {
            
                            field:"ProductName",
            
                            dir: "asc"
            
                        },
                        pageSize: 100
            
                    });
                    
                                    $("#filterable-listview").kendoMobileListView({
            
                        dataSource: foo,
            
                        template: $("#mobile-listview-filtering-template").text(),
            
                        filterable: {
            
                            field: "ProductName",
            
                            operator: "startswith"
            
                        },
            
                        endlessScroll: true
            
                    });
                    
            
                }
                    
            
         </script>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your listView create script inside a tabStrip's [`show`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip#events-show) or [`activate`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip#events-activate)(choose which one better fit in your case) event:

```
$("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
    animation:  {
        open: {
            effects: "fadeIn"
        }
    },
    activate: function(e) {
        mobileListViewFiltering(e.item);
    }
});
```

This will create your listView only when a tab is activated.

Comment: Thanx for the answer but it didn't work for me. Maybe i was doing something wrong but what i didn't understand is if i call my method with #tabstrip id how is it gonna know which tab is it?

Comment: `e.item` is the current tab.

Comment: @CanCode any result on this?

Comment: Sorry, we gave up on kendo and used ionic a long time ago.